# Solving the trigonometric problem ${\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 52{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 67{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\frac{{\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}} + \tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan {{40}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan {{40}^{\circ}}}}{{\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 52{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 67{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}$

My approach is as follow

$T = \frac{{\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}} + \tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan {{40}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan {{40}^{\circ}}}}{{\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 52{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 67{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}} = \frac{N}{D}$

$\tan {50^{\circ}} = \frac{{\tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}} \Rightarrow \tan 42{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} = \tan {50^{\circ}}\left( {1 - \tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}} \right)$

$N = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 42{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} + \tan {40^{\circ}}\left( {\tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}} \right)$

$N = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 42{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} + \tan {40^{\circ}}\tan {50^{\circ}}\left( {1 - \tan 42{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}} \right)$

$N = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 42{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\left( {1 - \tan {{40}^{\circ}}\tan {{50}^{\circ}}} \right) + \tan {40^{\circ}}\tan {50^{\circ}}$

$\tan {90^{\circ}} = \frac{{\tan {{50}^{\circ}} + \tan {{40}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan {{50}^{\circ}}\tan {{40}^{\circ}}}} \Rightarrow \tan {50^{\circ}}\tan {40^{\circ}} = 1$

$N = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 42{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\left( {1 - 1} \right) + 1 \Rightarrow N = 1$

$D = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 52{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\tan 67{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}$

$\tan 52{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} = \frac{{\tan {{45}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan {{45}^{\circ}}\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}} = \frac{{1 + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}$

$\tan 67{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}} = \frac{{\tan {{60}^{\circ}} + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan {{60}^{\circ}}\tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}} = \frac{{\sqrt 3  + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \sqrt 3 \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}$

$D = \tan 7{\frac{1}{2}^{\circ}}\left( {\frac{{1 + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 3  + \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}{{1 - \sqrt 3 \tan 7{{\frac{1}{2}}^{\circ}}}}} \right)$

The Denominator portion is getting complicated , how we will do it.

Comment: Use half angle identities twice: $7\frac12^\circ=\frac12 15^\circ=\frac12\frac12 30^\circ$.

Comment: I thought of it but it is getting complicated

Comment: https://www.math-only-math.com/exact-value-of-tan-7-and-half-degree.html

Comment: @Andrei I know the value of $tan 7.5^0$ but substitution is cumversome